# ASP.NET Web API How to send multiple POST requests one by one in a single controller method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, webapi

I have a collection of objects. How to send each object from this collection in a separate post request  in a controller method, so that they are sent one by one and only after all requests are sent, method execution is finished ?

Comment: You want to send objects from server to client or from client to server or from one server to another server?

Comment: I use httpclient and send post request to target uri of api, which I am consuming

Comment: Then you can loop thru the collection of objects and call API for each of the objects... Did you try doing it? What's the issue you are facing?